# why my delay function is not working in Jquery when i use it to delay $(document).ready ? help me out

Tags: jquery, delay, document-ready

I want that my [div](http://jsfiddle.net/wH7YU/132/) to shows up just after 5 seconds document is ready so I used

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    delay(function(){
        $('#up').slideDown("slow");
    },4000);
});
```

but it's not working, the document loads when I don't use delay function.
It works using :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.hidden').slideDown("slow");
    },4000);
});
```

And I don't want to use `set-timeout` function so how can I do this with delay function.

Comment: Why do you not want to use `setTimeout`? This is exactly what it is for. I assume you're confused about jQuery's `delay()`, which would not work anyway because it's designed to delay actions in the jQuery animation queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no method called delay in javascript, you need to use setTimeout as you shown above.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.hidden').slideDown("slow");
    }, 4000);
});
```

There is a [.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) method provided by jQuery, it is for delays items added in the queue

```
$('.hidden').delay(4000).slideDown("slow");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tXumG/)

still if you don't want to use `setTimeout` then create an alias for it like (**Just for fun**)

```
var delay = setTimeout;
delay(function () {
    $('.hidden').slideDown("slow");
}, 4000);
```

Comment: OP mentioned that it is working with `setTimeout` but he don't wanna use it

Comment: @TusharGupta that is the solution to OP's problem

Comment: @TusharGupta OP want to show the element after 4 second so it is not the time to do animation as done by you... the showing has to start after 4 seconds

Comment: yes i know but there is not alternative of using `setTimeout`

Comment: @TusharGupta then that is the answer... not using slideDown with 4 sec animation

Comment: @TusharGupta what to do... that is what the OP is asking for

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code

[.slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)

```
$('#up').slideDown(4000); //time in ms
```

Comment: This will make the `slideDown` take 4 seconds, not wait for 4 seconds for it to happen.

Comment: yes i know but there is not alternative of using `setTimeout` which he don't want.

Comment: But it doesn't meet his requirements.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan giving him a choice coz he already has the answer `setTimeout` .

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/wH7YU/137/)**

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.hidden').delay(4000).slideDown("slow");
});
```

Hope this helps,Thank you